# How to make a text that changes and animates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am currently practicing some html and css, along with some basic javascript.
I want to make a text that changes after a period like:

i Hello i

ii Hello ii

iii Hello iii

Or something like that, you get the idea.
 I want it to change after a small period like half a second. After searching the internet and stackoverflow, I haven't found a solution yet. 
Can someone direct me on how to do it properly?

Comment: Use `setInterval();` to get the old innerHTML and add `i` at both sides... Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nz86v65f/

Comment: Daniel Fazlijevic, you need three changes or infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Use setInterval and below function to do that:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("foo");
var countOfI = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  if (countOfI > 10) countOfI = 1;
  var i = new Array(countOfI).fill('i').join("");
  el.innerHTML = i + " Hello " + i;
  countOfI++;
}, 500)
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```